# how to remove positions in a nested for loop?

Tags: java

getLength and getWidth are currently set to int values 6 and 3, so this gives me a rectangle. I would like to remove the inside and leave the perimeter. i know i need an if else condition inside of the inner loop, and probably need to use the && operator, but cant come up with something concrete and functional. Can i get some ideas.

```
public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < getLength(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < getWidth(); j++) {
                System.out.print("o ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the current output, and what is the desired output?

Comment: Don't try to 'remove' the inner chars, try 'not to print' the inner chars (or print whitespaces instead).

Comment: Another hint, divide and conquer: 1. draw the upper border, 2. draw (getLength() - 2) times only the first and last character, and inbetween only whitespaces, 3. draw the lower border

Comment: well i cant post the current output, unless i answer my own question but its a rectangle of circles "o" of size 6X3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep you need an if like

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
 {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
        {
            if (i > 0 && i < getLength() -1 && j > 0 && j < getWidth() -1) 
            {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.print("o ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
}
```

**Output**

```
o o o 
o   o 
o   o 
o   o 
o   o 
o o o
```